# How to set default title on react navigation if the string is empty?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

React Navigation uses the default parameter in "navigation.getParam('Title', 'Default Title')" if it can't find a parameter named 'Title'. But I have my code set up so that the parameter title refers to one of the props, which can either be the title of the page, or an empty string. (It never becomes undefined). How do I set the title to the default parameter if 'Title' is an empty string, instead of being undefined?

For some context, this happens because my parameter 'Title' is being set from the props from the redux store, which can sometimes take a while to get populated. I have measures to prevent the screen from loading until it gets populated, but I still want to have a fall back in case something goes wrong.

Comment: `But I have my code set up so that the parameter title refers to one of the props` Please show your code and how you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string must be undefined to show de Default Title, why can't you add a inline condition?

`props.title === ''? undefined : props.title`